# JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot read property 'document' of null, when tried to get the edited contents from ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my `gwt` project. The editor is being displayed but when i try to get the edited content, using the method `getHTML()` of class CKEditor,

i get an exception :-

```
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot read property 'document' of null     at  com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)   at 

com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)   at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)     at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)   at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)  at              com.gwtck.client.CKEditor.getNativeHTML(CKEditor.java)  at com.gwtck.client.CKEditor.getHTML(CKEditor.java:162)         at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)  at  com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)  at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)   at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)     at  com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)  at  com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)    at  com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)   at  com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)     at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)     at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)  at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)   at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor337.invoke(Unknown Source)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Vikram, could you please format the stacktrace by editing your question so it becomes readable?

Comment: @w4rumy, ya sure i will keep in mind while posting the questions in future.

Comment: You can edit this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17343238/edit